# Django HTTP 500 Error

Tags: python, django, http, templates

I am creating a custom HTTP 500 error template.  Why is it Django shows it when i raise an exception and not when I return HttpResponseServerError (I just get the default browser 500 error)?  I find this behaviour strange...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `HttpResponseServerError` inherits from `HttpResponse` and is actually quite simple:

```
class HttpResponseServerError(HttpResponse):
    status_code = 500
```

So let's look at the `HttpResponse` constructor:

```
def __init__(self, content='', *args, **kwargs):
    super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Content is a bytestring. See the `content` property methods.
    self.content = content
```

As you can see by default `content` is empty.

Now, let's take a look at how it is called by Django itself (an excerpt from django.views.defaults):

```
def server_error(request, template_name='500.html'):
    """
    500 error handler.

    Templates: :template:`500.html`
    Context: None
    """
    try:
        template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return http.HttpResponseServerError('<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>')
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render(Context({})))
```

As you can see when you produce a server error, the template named 500.html is used, but when you simply return `HttpResponseServerError` the content is empty and the browser falls back to it's default page.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis.  So what would be the proper convention in this case? To pass my template to the HttpResponseServerError? Or just to raise the exception?

Comment: I would prefer raising an exception for several reasons. First of all you can utilize the Django Middleware mechanism (have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process_exception) and add some logging and handling of specific exceptions and such, second you can write your own custom 500 view (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view).

Comment: Third, 500 means Internal Server Error, that is - something really messed up. There is no point in handling this at a place where the only handling you can do is to say "well, yeah, something really messed up". Let the error follow it's natural path and if you can't properly handle it, let Django handle it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Put this below in the urls.py.

```
#handle the errors    
from django.utils.functional import curry
from django.views.defaults import *

handler500 = curry(server_error, template_name='500.html')
```

Put 500.html in your templates. Just as simple like that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with another browser ? Is your custom error page larger than 512 bytes ? It seems some browsers (including Chrome) replace errors page with their own when the server's answer is shorter than 512 bytes.

Comment: weird.. When I return HttpResponseServerError it works but when I return HttpResponseServerError() it doesn't.  Isn't it correct to have the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 2+ all you need to do is put the corresponding error templates in your base templates folder. Django will automatically render them before rendering the default.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/views/#error-views

In your case just drop your template '500.html' (or '404.html') into /templates